# Comment removed. Was it too chatty?

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

Someone posted a comment below my answer over here:

[Difference among 'public', 'default', 'protected', and 'private'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052)

I don't remember the exact wording, but it was something like:

> Nice table! It's so intuitive. I wish you had posted this earlier!

The comment is gone now and I'm curious why. Was it too chatty? Is there a post somewhere here on meta describing what is to be seen as too chatty? I've seen far more "chatty" comments elsewhere. Is it appropriate to flag those? (Personally I don't mind chatty comments that much.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Was it too chatty?

Yes.

It doesn't add anything to the answer. It isn't constructive to the general users of the site.

> Is it appropriate to flag those?

Absolutely.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response Oded. To me it just seems like someone shared their subjective opinion of the answer. Someone wanted to express that they thought the table was intuitive. Is "Good short answer ! Clear and Concise" (posted on another answer on that question) a not too chatty? How about "never start a paragraph with, 'when exposing members'..." (also posted on the same page) which is more like a joke?

Comment: Yes, both are too chatty. If the second had actual pertinent information, that's different, but if it is just a joke - too chatty. Comments have always been seen as temporary - if they have important information, it should be edited into the post, either way - they subject to deletion without warning.

Comment: Ok! This is new to me, but it makes a lot of sense. It keeps each page clear if comments are kept clean and to the point. Thanks again Oded.

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding on Oded's answer:

The comment did not really provide any substance (it talked about your formatting). It's one of those things that should have just been a vote.

I've flagged a number of these, and my flags are always marked helpful.

That being said, I think it's important to clean up posts that are popular or have long comment sections. They just end up being noise, and new users may get the wrong idea about what comments are for.